How to show that a polytope is not integral?

Consider a graph $G(V,E)$ with $n:= \lvert V(G) \rvert$ and the corresponding polytope $$Q := \left\{ x \in [0, 1]^{E} : \sum_{e \in E} x_e = n - 1, \, \sum_{e \in \delta(X)} x_e \geq 1 \text{ for all } \emptyset \subseteq X \subseteq V \right\}.$$
Show that $Q$ is not integral.
Hint: Use the graph Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph with $V = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $E = \{ \{i, i+1\} \mod 5 \mid i = 0, \ldots, 4\} \cup \{0, 3\}$.
The only edges with non-zero weights are $\{0, 1\}, \{1, 2\}$, and $\{2, 3\}$, each with a weight of $1$. (See below for a sketch of the graph.)

I do not understand how the hinted graph is supposed to help here, especially what the edge weights are good for. Could you please give me a hint?


What is $\delta(X)$?

The neighbours of the set $X$.

Do you mean the edges that go out of $X$?

Yeah, exactly. Sorry for the typo above.

Your $\subseteq$ should be (strict) $\subset$ in both places.  That is, omit $X = \emptyset$ and $X=V$ from the constraints.

Hint: Show that $$\min_{x\in Q} \sum_{(i,j)\in E} c_{ij} x_{ij}$$ is fractional for that choice of edge weights $c_{ij}$.
